# How to set file permissions for a whole disk using the command line in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

How can I change the permissions for a complete local disk (and all the files and folders within it) using the command prompt?

My username is `XYZ` and drive is `local disk I`.

Answer (score 4):

### Takeown

You can use [`takeown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024.aspx) for this.

> Enables an administrator to recover access to a file that previously was denied, by making  **the administrator the owner of the file**.

Example:

```
takeown /r /d y /f *
```

Where:

- `/r`: Is a recursive operation on all files in the specified directory and subdirectories.
- `/d`: Suppresses the confirmation prompt that is displayed when the current user does not have the *List Folder* permission on a specified directory.
- `/f`: Specifies the file name or directory name pattern. You can use the wildcard character **`*`** when specifying the pattern.

---

### Icacls

You can also use the [`icacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28WS.10%29.aspx) utility for this.

> Displays or modifies discretionary access control lists (DACLs) on specified files, and applies stored DACLs to files in specified directories.

Example:

```
icacls "D:\path" /grant YOURUSER:(OI)(CI)F
```

Where:

- `F`:  Full Control.
- `CI`: Container Inherit - This flag indicates that subordinate containers will inherit this ACE.
- `OI`: Object Inherit - This flag indicates that subordinate files will inherit the ACE.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also needed to cascade the permissions to all files using

```
icacls "D:\path" /reset /T /C
```

after using icalcs above

Comment: (1) Can you explain exactly what the `/T` and `/C` options do? (2) In what way was the command in the other answer inadequate?  What problem(s) did you have after using it?  … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.